# success handler for $.ajax function with a non-standard http status code

Tags: jquery, ajax

We've written a RESTful server API.  For whatever reason, we made the decision that for DELETEs, we would like to return a 204 (No Content) status code, with an empty response.  I'm trying to call this from jQuery, passing in a success handler and setting the verb to DELETE:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:'DELETE',
    url: url,
    success: callback,
});
```

The server returns a 204, but the success handler is never called.  Is there a way I can configure jQuery to allow 204s to fire the success handler?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`204` should be treated as success. What version of jQuery are you using? I did a couple of tests and all 200 range status codes went to the success handler. The source for [jQuery 1.4.2](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L631) confirms this:

```
// Determines if an XMLHttpRequest was successful or not
httpSuccess: function( xhr ) {
    try {
        // IE error sometimes returns 1223 when 
        // it should be 204 so treat it as success, see #1450
        return !xhr.status && location.protocol === "file:" ||
            // Opera returns 0 when status is 304
            ( xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300 ) ||
            xhr.status === 304 || xhr.status === 1223 || xhr.status === 0;
    } catch(e) {}

    return false;
},
```

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused.  I'm trying this again, and it appears to be working. It looks like I must have been doing something else incorrectly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had a simliar issue because my script was also sending the "Content-Type" header as "application/json". While the request succeeded, it couldn't JSON.parse an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    ...
    error: function(xhr, errorText) {
        if(xhr.status==204) successCallback(null, errorText, xhr);
        ...
    },
    ...
});
```

ugly...but might help

Comment: Thanks sje397, that makes sense.  You think it's the only way?

Answer (score 3):

**It's technically a problem on your server**
Like Paul said, an an empty 204 response with a server content-type of json is treated by jQuery as an error.
**You can get around it in jQuery by manually overriding dataType to 'text'.**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType:'text',
    success:(data){
       //I will now fire on 204 status with empty content
       //I have beaten the machine.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is alternative way to callback on success... I think that will work for you.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType:'text',
    statusCode: {
                204: function (data) {
                   logic here
                }
});
```